# Дан массив символов. Определить, сколько раз входит в него группа букв abc

Tags: c++

```
char str[80] = "abcgbe q$1  b56bcg#r4 6c aeg "; //строка символов
char token[4] = "abc";
char *p, *t;

cout << str << '\n';

p = str;    
//t = token;

int count = 0;
while (*p){ 
    t = token;      
    if (*(++p) == *(++t))
        count++;

    ++p;
}

cout << count << '\n';
```

Не могу понять, он у меня сравнивает по первой букве, почему так?

Comment: Потому что вы ему об этом явно сказали. Не ленитесь, прошагайте ваш код в отладчике. Своими глазами всё увидите, это будет быстрей, чем ждать что это сделает кто-то за вас. И ещё: на этом этапе вам на стоит использовать конструкции вида  `if (*(++p) == *(++t))`. Они, конечно, выглядят круто, но за ними вы не видите простейших ошибок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И охота изобрелать велосипеды?

```
char str[80] = "abcgbe q$1  b56bcg#r4 6c aeg ";
char token[4] = "abc";
char *p = str;    
size_t count = 0, tsize = strlen(token); // OR (sizeof(token)-1)

while( *p )
{
    if( !memcmp( p, token, tsize ) ) 
    { 
         count++; p += tsize;
    }
    else p++;
}
```

P.S. Кстати, в этом коде есть ошибка! Предлагаю найти её самостоятельно для разминки :)

Comment: Угу, ошибку вижу :) Интересно, как бы её поизящнее исправить?

Comment: `if (tsize <= strlen(str)) do { ... } while ( *(p + tsize) )`?

Comment: А вот задумался: надо ли на самом деле? Если это C-строки.

Comment: Ну, если `tsize` _очень_ большой, то за конец `str` вылезет прилично...

Comment: Ну побегаем лишнего :) Мне-то больше думалось, что если нет 0 в конце str, и её размер задан явно, то словить access violation под конец  можно запросто.

Comment: Побег в невыделенную память чреват [вылетом](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx). Ну и по стандарту UB, так что...

Comment: Если у нас нули в конце, то memcmp до неё не доберётся.

Comment: Хм. И правда. А это гарантировано? Я и правда не знаю. То есть наверное должно быть, но вдруг он читает кусками, равными размеру слова, для ускорения? Всё равно для этого неинициализированная память должна быть в пределах слова, что нереалистично. В общем, вопрос вроде бы и правда больше теоретический.

Comment: Да, тут мы упираемся в поведение memcmp. В моём мане сказано так: "*For a nonzero return value, the sign is determined by the sign of the difference  between  the first pair of bytes (interpreted as unsigned char) that differ in s1 and s2.*"

Comment: Хм: [The memcmp function reports the result of the comparison at the point of the first difference, but it can still read past that point](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/14/10075623.aspx): If t happened to sit right at the end of a page, and the next page was uncommitted memory, then you take an access violation while trying to read tchunk. Your optimization turned into a crash.

Comment: Ага, значит, не зря переживали :)